# Do 90% of startups fail?

Tags: economics, business

I have seen this claim made in several popular websites that 90% of startups fail. Two examples:

> When the founder of a startup company shuts down her or his business,
> it’s customary to pen an essay that tells the rest of the community
> what went wrong. Call it a failure post-mortem. Nine out of 10
> startups fail, which is why the failure post-mortem has become so
> common that it’s practically a Silicon Valley cliché.
>
> [fortune.com](http://fortune.com/2014/09/25/why-startups-fail-according-to-their-founders/)

..

> Most entrepreneurs think they’re building the next big thing.
> In reality, over 90% of them fail.
>
> [medium.com](https://medium.com/swlh/why-90-of-startups-fail-and-what-to-do-about-it-b0af17b65059)

I found some statistics in [smallbiztrends.com](https://smallbiztrends.com/2019/03/startup-statistics-small-business.html):

> Of all small businesses started in 2014:
>
> 80 percent made it to the second year (2015);
> 70 percent made it to the third year (2016);
> 62 percent made it to the fourth year (2017);
> 56 percent made it to the fifth year (2018).

This stat is saying 44% of startups fail within the first five years. But it is incomplete.

My question is, do 90% of the startups fail?

Comment: What would it mean for a startup not to fail? How many years does it have to last?

Comment: "Small business" and "startup" are absolutely not the same thing. It is perfectly reasonable for these to have different failure rates.

Comment: And what constitutes "success"? Companies like Uber and Spotify are running permanently on investment money. They keep making losses every single year, but investors keeps pumping new money in. Success for the founders, but I wouldn't call them successful _companies_.

Comment: I think it's clear that "fail" means cease operations, or "shut down permanently".

Comment: @fredsbend: I don't think it's all that clear. First of all, success or failure of a business can come in grades. For a VC investor, failures may include start ups that don't start up that much (so no buy out) but that reach a profitable state of "normal" (non-start-up) businesses. OTOH, a successful small business, say, a freelancer, may have a "buy out" in the form that the business owner is hired. So the business shuts down, but successfully so. If you'd look at my business, you'll see me switching back and forth between [part-time] employement and my business. This is solely because some..

Comment: ... of my customers are sometimes bound in a way that employing me is feasible for them but subcontracting me is not. And I know other freelancers where you'd see similar patterns (who take e.g. interim management positions). Last but not least, if you are not looking at the high-tech sector: when economy is difficult in general, people without job may start a business to earn their living. Even if that business is profitable, they may prefer employment as soon as there's a chance and in consequence close the business.

Comment: Contractors and temporarily self-employed are clearly not the topic here. Neither of those are start ups, as the term is typically used.

Comment: @called2voyage My own opinion is that if a startup gives lower than 1x return after two years of operation, it is a failure. But there might be other better definitions. I am open to read and learn from them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR In the US, fewer than 90% of startups fail in the first 10 years. In India, more than 90% startups in India fail in the first 5 years. Failure rates depend on year and region. First-time entrepreneurs are more likely to fail.**

According to [IBM](https://www-03.ibm.com/press/in/en/pressrelease/52424.wss) (emphasis IBM's and not mine):

> More than 90% startups in India fail in their first 5 years. Lack of pioneering innovation (77%) is the topmost reason for the failure of most Indian startups.
>
> ...
>
> The IBM study, ***“Entrepreneurial India”*** is based on interviews with more than 1,300 Indian executives, including 600 startup entrepreneurs, 100 venture capitalists, 100 government leaders, 500 leaders of established companies and 22 educational institution leaders to analyze the macro impact of startups on the economic growth of the country.

The [Bureau of Labor Statistics](https://www.bls.gov/) (BLS) has a neat [table](https://www.bls.gov/bdm/us_age_naics_00_table7.txt) showing survival rates of establishments (workplaces) from 1994 to now. For each year, the table shows the survival rate of all businesses founded a certain year. (At the time of founding, the business would be a startup. Thus, this table shows startup survival rate.) For example, 17% of businesses founded between March 1993 and March 1994 were still around in March 2018. These statistics show survival rates do vary year-to-year. Thus, it is reasonable to assume startup survival rates vary year-to-year.

The BLS also published a [study](https://www.bls.gov/opub/mlr/2011/09/art2full.pdf) analyzing the success and employment rates of Silicon Valley startups. This article uses "Silicon Valley high-tech firm" and "Silicon Valley startup" synonymously.

> The majority of high-tech businesses born in 2000 did
> not survive past 2003. ... By 2009, fewer than 1
> in 5 high-tech startups born in 2000 were still in business.
> The 2000 cohort’s highest annual survival rate, 93 percent,
> occurred in its first year. This finding is consistent with
> those from previous studies, which also show that businesses generally have higher survival rates in their first
> year. The reason is that new businesses often have enough
> initial reserves to survive for at least 1 year.

Chart 2 on page 4 of the pdf shows that in 2008, the survival rate of startups founded in Silicon Valley in 2000 was slightly under 20%. The datapoints for future years are not displayed, but the survival appears to have plateaued. Going back to the table, we see a 38.6 survival rate nationwide. Thus, perhaps unsurprisingly, survival rate varies by region as well. The BLS study further stated:

> About 28
> percent of a typical cohort of high-tech firms survive past
> 9 years; however, only 17.1 percent of the 2000 cohort
> survived that long.

Chart A-1 on page 13 shows ~15% of Silicon Valley startups survive for 15 years. From the table, ~25% of US startups survive for 15 years.

Less credibly, an [article](https://s3.amazonaws.com/startupcompass-public/StartupGenomeReport2_Why_Startups_Fail_v2.pdf) titled "Startup Genome Report Extra
on Premature Scaling: A deep dive into why most high growth startups fail"  coauthored by researchers from
UC Berkeley & Stanford writes:

> More than 90% of startups
> fail, due primarily to self-destruction rather than competition. For the less than
> 10% of startups that do succeed, most encounter several near death
> experiences along the way.

The timespan is unclear.

A Harvard Business School article titled "Performance Persistence in
Entrepreneurship" writes:

> 52% of computer startups founded in 1983 eventually went
> public, while only 18% of computer companies founded in 1985 ultimately succeeded.

This demonstrates the high variability between year of founding and survival and reflects the concept of "market timing."

Later on:

> The overall success rate on first-time ventures is 25.3%. Not surprisingly, serial
> entrepreneurs have an above-average success rate of 36.9% in their first ventures. It is more
> interesting that in their subsequent ventures they have a significantly higher success rate
> (29.0%) than do first-time entrepreneurs (25.3%).

Thus, the chance that *your* startup will fail (when you have not created other startups) is higher and the 90% statistic *may* apply to you and be sensible general advice.

> **Do 90% of startups fail?**

The failure of a startup depends on many factors such as experience, timing, and location. According to IBM, 90% of startups in India do fail within 5 years. In the US, it is highly likely that **fewer** than 90% of startups fail in a 15 year period.

Comment: Looks like the number 17% and 18% came up more than once. So, it looks like it is reasonable to say 1 in 5 startups succeed in the US. For India, it is 1 in 10 I assume.

Comment: Interesting... I wouldn't consider a 15 year old company a startup - in fact, maybe not even a 5 year old company.

Comment: @Michael Many companies that have existed for 4-6 years are now considered startups. I saw some news articles that refer to brave (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_(web_browser)) as a startup though it is like 5 years old. Either the definition of startup is changing or different people interpret it differently, right?

Comment: @SakibArifin Thanks for pointing this out! I can see the answer changing too depending on the exact definition of a startup (which doesn't seem to be discussed in the Fortune and Medium articles).